# Which spring-data-elasticsearch version choose for specific elasticsearch version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Sorry about the trivial question but I have just started studying `spring`.

I am checking a version compatibility table between `spring-data-elasticsearch`, `spring-boot` and `elasticsearch` in this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions).

It is specifying a `elasticsearch` version  with only one version of `spring-data-elasticsearch` and `spring-boot`.

I am not sure that it means that each `spring-data-elasticsearch` and `spring-boot` version guarantee only the specific `elasticsearch` version but any other versions so that it must choose the `spring-data-elasticsearch`, `spring-boot` version matched to each `elasticsearch` version.

Answer (score 0):

This table show for Spring Data Elasticsearch which versions of Elasticsearch and Spring were used to build and test the respective version of Spring Data Elasticsearch; these are dependencies of Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Once a version of Spring Data Elasticsearch is released (currently 5.1.1), the used Elasticsearch version will only be increased for patch releases, so it will stay on 8.7.x.

That does not mean, that this version will not work with Elasticsearch 8.6 or an upcoming 8.8 version, but it's not built and tested with these versions, you have to thoroughlly test your application if you use different versions.

As for the Spring Boot version: This is no dependency of Spring Data Elasticsearch, it is more an information which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch is pulled in by Spring Boot.